# Google ML-Engine Predict from C# Authentication issue

Tags: c#, google-api, gcloud, google-oauth, google-cloud-ml

Followed

[OAuth example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45218976/how-do-i-get-online-predictions-in-c-sharp-for-my-model-on-cloud-machine-learnin)

successfully getting bearer token, but response is:

```
{StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Vary: X-Origin
  Vary: Referer
  Vary: Origin
  Vary: Accept-Encoding
  X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
  X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  Alt-Svc: hq=":443"; ma=2592000; quic=51303433; quic=51303432; quic=51303431; quic=51303339; quic=51303335,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="43,42,41,39,35"
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Accept-Ranges: none
  Cache-Control: private
  Date: Thu, 03 May 2018 13:29:53 GMT
  Server: ESF
  WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="https://accounts.google.com/"
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
}}
```

using a service account with 'ML Engine Developer' Role.
Here is the code:

```
        var url = $"{googleapiprojecturl}/models/{modelname}/versions/{version}:predict";
        GoogleCredential credential;
        using (Stream stream = new FileStream(@"C:\serviceacctkey.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream);
        }
        var bearer_token = await credential.UnderlyingCredential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync(url);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", bearer_token);
        var content = new StringContent(payloadJsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var responseMessage = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
        responseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

where googleapiprojecturl = https://ml.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{projectID}

Comment: What IAM permissions does that service account have?

Comment: Has 'ML Engine Developer', just added 'Service Account Token Creator', no change.. the token was and is being generated.

Comment: Added 'Project Editor' also, no change.

Comment: I can't look at this in detail right now, but it's possible you need to add the correct scopes to the service credential. I.e. `credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream).CreateScoped(...);`

Comment: Note also that you can probably use this package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.CloudMachineLearningEngine.v1/ rather than calling the JSON/REST enpoint directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as Chris suggested above, as comment on the question, the answer was scope on the credential before asking for token:

```
credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream).CreateScoped(new[] { CloudMachineLearningEngineService.Scope.CloudPlatform });
```

Comment: Great, glad it's sorted out :)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this in C#, but I also had trouble in Python with the following similar code:

```
# Doesn't work
# creds = GoogleCredentials.from_stream(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE)
```

In Python, the following worked instead:

```
from oauth2client import service_account
creds = service_account.ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('key.json', SCOPES)
creds.get_access_token()
```

In C#, it looks like you would use the [`ServiceAccountCredentials`](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/reference/1.10.0/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Auth_1_1OAuth2_1_1ServiceAccountCredential) class.

Comment: Made the changes you suggested (same result) like this:                 ServiceAccountCredential credential;
                using (Stream stream = new FileStream(@"C:\serviceacctkey.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
                {
                    credential = ServiceAccountCredential.FromServiceAccountData(stream);
                }
                var bearer_token = await credential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync(url);

Comment: I'll try to dig into this, but it may take a few days. Can you confirm that you are able to send requests from gcloud? Are you willing to try Python simply for validation?

Comment: Yes, this model/version works from curl, gcloud, etc.